# How to merge two arrays in C using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know how to insert one array into pointer array. But I`m not able to merge arrays to a pointer array...
Please can anyone help me to create a pointer array by merging two arrays....

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n,m,i,A[100],B[100], *C;

    printf("Enter size of A Array: \n");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter elements for A array: \n");

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        C++;
    }   
    C=&A[0];
    printf("\n Element in array are :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d",(*C));
        C++;
    }
    printf("Enter size of B Array: \n");

    scanf("%d",&m);

    printf("Enter elements for B array: \n");

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)

    {
        scanf("%d",&B[i]);
        C++;
    }   
    C=&B[0];
    printf("\n Element in array are :\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d",(*C));
        C++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Instead of `C=&A[0];`, you can have `C=A`.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? I understood that you want to merge two arrays but didn't get this -> `using pointers`?

Comment: What do you think should happen when you merge two arrays?  What are the inputs, and what is the output?  You've shown how to read two arrays, and print them.  What do you expect to be the output from the merge operation?  Show some example data — maybe 5 elements for A and 7 for B (or vice versa) and the output you expect from the merged data.  It isn't clear what you mean by "inserting into a pointer array".  You're using a pointer to access the data stored in a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge two `arrays`,you just need to copy the two `array` elements into a single array,you can write a simple code using pointers:

```
int main(){

int n,m,i,*A,*B,size=100;

A=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
B=malloc(size*sizeof(int));

printf("Enter size of A Array: \n");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Enter elements for A array: \n");
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);

printf("Enter size of B Array: \n");
scanf("%d",&m);

printf("Enter elements for B array: \n");
for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    scanf("%d",&B[i]);

for(i=n;i<n+m;i++){
   if(i>=size){
   size*=2;
   A=realloc(A,size*sizeof(int));
   A[i]=B[i];
   }
} 
printf("\n Element in array are :\n");
for(i=0;i<m+n;i++)
{
    printf("\t%d",(*A));
    C++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think the single pointer will be used in this case,
with single pointer if you initialized the first array(take for an example 3 elements 1,2,3) and then you have to initialize it to the first location of the first array to print the sequence and then with the second array (3 elements 4,5,6)
{after the first for loop :: C=&B[0]} so in the first for loop i hav incremented the C pointer and after that loop that means the next C location i have set the pointer to  C=&B[0] and then do the same with the B array and set the pointer to the initial location and printed the values it gives the first tree values and some garbage values(the leftovers of the A array it didn't go to the B array address idk why)
so i hav used the array of pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n,m,i,j,A[100],B[100], *C[100];
printf("Enter size of A Array: \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter elements for A array: \n");
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",(A+i));
    *(C+i)=A+i;

} 
printf("Enter size of B Array: \n");
scanf("%d",&m);
printf("Enter elements for B array: \n");
for (j=0;j<m;j++)
{
    scanf("%d",(B+j));
    *(C+i+j)=B+j;
}   
for (i=0;i<(n+m);i++){
printf("%d\t",*(C[i]));
}
return 0;
}
```